# iterate through dataframe columns and determine which are numeric

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a read data from from a csv file. I'd like to write code that does the following—

(1) starts iterating through each column (I imagine a for loop)

(2) determines if a column contains only numbers

(3) if the column is numeric, print certain statistical information about that specific column & whether that column is normally distributed (skewness & kurtosis between -1 and 1)

(4) if the column is not numeric, skip over it

This is for an Intro Python course, so it is not expected to be complex

**So far this is my code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file path')

columns = list(df)

for i in columns:
(if column is numeric, print: Column Title, min, max, mean, median, "Yes column normal" or "No column not normal")
(else, just skip it)
```

Comment: Are you aware of [`df.describe()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html)?

Comment: @KentShikama Somewhat, yes. However, before I use describe(), I need to understand how to iterate through the columns and determine if they are numeric or not.

Comment: `describe` operates on the entire Dataframe; you don't have to select numeric columns for it.

Comment: I would have loved if my task were to simply use describe(), but it is just slightly more involved than that.

Comment: You're given data but you don't know what it is or which columns correspond to what? What is the issue, by the way? Have you read the Pandas docs?

Comment: @AMC Not sure I understand you. I know what the data is and where it comes from. However, describe() is not sufficient for what I am wanting to do.

Comment: @mathmajor I’m confused then, why do you need to check the columns like this?

Answer (score 0):

```
for column in df: 
    if np.issubdtype(df[column], np.number): 
        print(df[column]) # print(df[column].describe()) or whatever other stats
```